# Is there a Stack Exchange for paleontology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I’m interested in paleontology so I want to know if there is a Stack Exchange for paleontology. And if there is, please provide me the name and link.

Comment: Do you have a specific question you want to ask?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your question, there are a few places you could try:

- [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/)
  For "*general questions about biological concepts*"
- [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)
  "*If your question is about meteorology, geophysics, geology, climatology, oceanography, geochemistry, or hydrology, then you are in the right place. The above list is not exhaustive, so if you feel your question is about earth science, go ahead and post it.*"
- [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)
  For questions about the astronomical event that wiped out a lot of prehistoric life.
- [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/)
  Logically excludes prehistory, but for questions asking about the history of palaeontology, this would be the right site. A likely alternative is [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

**As always, read the per site Help pages, and if you're still unsure your question is appropriate, you can ask on their respective meta sites.**

Answer (score 4):

The topic seems to be more or less equally divided between the [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) and [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) sites. Both have a [palaeontology] tag with (now, as of December 2022) approximately a hundred questions.

- [[palaeontology] tag on Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palaeontology)
- [[palaeontology] tag on Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palaeontology)